# How to clear back forward list in UIWebview on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I want to access/clear the back forward list as if the `UIWebView` is new again. Is there any public API or workaround to do this?

I've tried:

```
while ([webview canGoback]) {
    [webview goBack];
}
```

but that will freeze the device (simulator too).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Disclaimer**
*As with anything like this, bear in mind that the results may not make it through app store approval and may not work at-all with future revisions of the SDK.*

---

There is no *official* method for doing this in the SDK. However if you really want to clear the back/forward history of a `UIWebView` it can be done with a little delve into the private frameworks.

A quick and dirty way to do it (complete with a bunch of ugly compiler warnings) is as follows:

Given that `myUIWebViewInstance` is a perfectly normal instance of `UIWebView`:

```
id internalWebView=[[myUIWebViewInstance _documentView] webView];       
[internalWebView setMaintainsBackForwardList:NO];
[internalWebView setMaintainsBackForwardList:YES];
```

There is also the rather tempting `_clearBackForwardCache` method in the framework, however it didn't seem to do much when tickled. Just flipping the boolian worked a treat for me.

Comment: Very sneaky code! We want the app to get in the app store so this doesn't benefit us. Mark correct because you said there was no official way. Too bad

Comment: No doubt about it, I was rejected today for using this exact code.

Comment: Apple just rejected one of my apps for using this private framework.

Comment: [internalWebView setMaintainsBackForwardList:NO]; setMaintainsBackForwardList method not found :(

Answer (score 13):

If you're trying to "reuse" an existing UIWebView, and disable the ability to go back to whatever previous page it was in before, you can:

1. When loading the new request (the one that user shouldn't go back from), save the URL of the new request, say like:

   `self.curURL = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.bla.com"];

   [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:curURL]];`
2. I'm guessing you have your own back button, so on your webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method, add:

   `backbttn.enabled = webView.canGoBack && ![[webView.request URL] isEqual: curURL];`

This way, the user won't even know that the UIWebView can go back to the page before.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I guess this doesn't exactly fit my situation. It would definitely be the correct answer for if I wan't to disable the ability to go back. My situation is I need to put the UIWebView at its root url so that I can display a toolbar to go with it and have a separate toolbar for any urls on top of it. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Great solution in most cases.  Seems to break when the URL redirects.  Still worth an up vote!

Answer (score 5):

I was successful (as far as you can call such a workaround 'successful') using the following line of code:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"if( window.history.length > 1 ) { window.history.go( -( window.history.length - 1 ) ) }; window.setTimeout( \"window.location.replace( '%@' )\", 300 );", targetLocation]];
```

where `targetLocation` is the desired URL as a `NSString`.

What it does is to tell the browser to go as far backwards as the history goes and then, after a short timeout, load the desired URL.

This of course does not solve the problem of clearing the forward going history (which I didn't need in my case).

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if programmatic back/forward navigation has been used before: in this case `history.length` is no longer in sync with the actual history stack and will show the number of user-navigated (by clicking links) pages. `history.length` will typically be larger than the number of pages you can go back, and `history.go(history.length-1)` is out of bounds and will quietly fail.

Answer (score 5):

Just recreate the webview. it would reset everything including history.

Comment: I tried that, but for whatever reason it lead to slow loading times....

Comment: It also clears the cache which you sometimes don't want to do. For instance, when you want to keep the contents of a shopping cart.

Comment: what do you mean by recreating the webivew ? doing alloc and init again

Answer (score 2):

I think if you release the uiwebview object and recreate then it would clear the history. I actually have a reverse problem. My uiwebview object automatically gets released during low memory event if it's inside a nonvisible view. I then have to recreate it in viewDidLoad but it does not retain the history from that point onwards.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you can break the history by manually loading some HTML...

Something like:

```
[webview loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:@""];
```

Comment: Hi Colin, thank you for your reply. Sadly, I would still need to go back to the first page in the list to do this. Even then, it will only override the pages after the first one. Leaving the fist one there

Answer (score 0):

Picking up Gilbert's clever approach: If modified, it does work with redirects (something it isn't capable of so far, as mharper pointed out).

Before loading the request, save the desired URL and set a boolean member variable called `_saveURL` to indicate that the redirect URL shall be saved (you will see the exact use of these two variables later):

```
- (void)my_loadURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; // create the request
    [_desiredURL release]; // clear up the previous value (assuming -my_loadURL: may be called multiple times)
    _desiredURL = [url retain]; // store the desired URL (will be used later)
    _saveURL = YES; // will also be used later
    [_webView loadRequest:request]; // start loading the request
}
```

(The retain and release calls of course won't be necessary if compiling in an Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) environment.)

Now in the `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate callback, check to see whether the redirect has already occured by testing whether the URL of the web view's current request differs from the desired URL. If so, save the redirect URL in a member variable `_firstURL`. This is also where `_saveURL` gets into place. It is to avoid overwriting `_firstURL` each time this delegate method is called.
Also, enable or disable the back and forward buttons just the way we did before.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // grab the URL currently being loaded
    NSURL *currentURL = [webview.request URL];

    // check whether we are supposed to save the redirect URL and
    // whether redirection has taken place yet
    if (_saveURL && ![currentURL isEqual:_desiredURL]) {
        [_firstURL release];
        _firstURL = [currentURL retain];
    }

    // adjust the enabled-state of the back and forward buttons just like before
    _backButton.enabled = _webView.canGoBack && ![currentURL isEqual:_firstURL];
    _forwardButton.enabled = _webView.canGoForward;
}
```

(Again, retain and release are not needed with ARC enabled.)

However, there's one key disadvantage of this method. It only works if you know for sure that the URL passed into `my_loadURL:` will redirect. Otherwise, the `_firstURL` variable will be set somewhen else. So if you can't tell whether the according URL will redirect, then this approach does not fit your needs. Anyway, it did fit my needs, and I hope I could help out someone else as well.

Update: You can improve this method by dropping all of that dealing with _desiredURL, meaning don't save the desired URL in `-my_loadURL:` and in `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` just say `if(_saveURL)`. This way, it'll work for websites that either don't redirect at all or that redirect instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried almost every solution posted without much success. My case is for Childbrowser phonegap plugin, but is based in the same problem, a single webview instance used to show external pages in my application. When I show an external page, the webview maintains the history of previous pages shown.
I wanted to remove the history when I show a new external webpage.

After some research, I've found a solution [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933433/447558) that worked for me.

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = \"\";"];
```

In the case of childbrowser, I placed it in the method `-(IBAction) onDoneButtonPress:(id)sender`, which previously inserted a blank page to start blank (but with back button enabled).

HTH!
Milton.