# I want to create an action that allows my users to delete UIWebView History

Tags: ios, xcode

I've found that the UIWebview with in my app is holding a lot of data and i want to allow the user to clear the history from the UIWebView, but as a fairly new programmer i don't quite know how to do this.

I'm using Xcode 4.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by history you mean the back and forward history the sorry there is no official way to delete history of UIWebView. There are few private methods (see this - [How to clear back forward list in UIWebview on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799918/how-to-clear-back-forward-list-in-uiwebview-on-iphone)) but if you use this your app will be rejected from app store.

Comment: Can I delete all the dat the app saves to the phone?