# setMaintainsBackForwardList method absent from UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to clear the history of a `webview` using the code above:

```
[_webView setMaintainsBackForwardList:NO];
```

But I am geting this erro message:

```
"No visible @interface for uiwebview declares the selector setMaintainsBackForwardList"
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear.

`UIWebView` has no such method, as you can easily confirm taking a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

`setMaintainsBackForwardList:` is a method of [WebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/setMaintainsBackForwardList:), a OSX class which has a different implementation.

In order to erase the back/forward history in a `UIWebView` you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799918/how-to-clear-back-forward-list-in-uiwebview-on-iphone) (beware that the accepted answer is likely to have your app rejected, as per the comments)