# How to clear history in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

I'd like to clear the back forward list of a `WKWebView` when the user taps a button.

I can't find anything useful in Apple documentation but I found the same question related to `UIWebView` : [How to clear back forward list in UIWebview on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3799918/3844377)

Unfortunately, I don't really like the given answers as they are either risky considering the app review process or they just don't work. So I was wondering if there was something new with `WKWebView` that could help me to achieve that. I'm kind of hopeless as it's been a while now that I'm looking for a solution but we never know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dirty workaround**

For now, I reinitialise my WKWebView ( myWebView = WKWebView() ) and I redefine its constraints ( as they are, of course, broken when I reinitialise the web view ).

What I don't really like here is that I reinitialise the whole web view whereas I just want to clear its back forward list.

Comment: I had to do the same in the end with my ```WKWebView``` (in my macOS app). Just don't forget to set the various properties again (i.e.: back/forward gestures, etc...).

Comment: I added wkwebview to my app form the uibuilder, and don't set any properties from code. How do I reinitialize and redefine it's constraints in this case? I am using objective C, main aim is to clear history, I will only load html and image files in the container Documents folder