# Clear UIWebView Content without a webViewDidFinishLoad delegate callback

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am looking for a way to clear a UIWebView content.  However I do not want the webViewDidFinishLoad to get called.  Not implementing UIWebViewDelegate is not an option for me in this case.

loadHTMLString and loadRequest with empty data won't work for me since this will trigger the webViewDidFinishLoad callback.

Using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: (as suggested in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933315/clear-uiwebview-content-upon-dismissal-of-modal-view-iphone-os-3-0/4127520#4127520)) will not trigger the callback.  But if the content was a PDF format, this would not clear the UIWebView' s content which I do need it to.

Any idea?

Comment: Recreate UIWebView and replace your current object with new one.

Comment: Can you not modify webViewDidFinishLoad to check the status of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Wain: that what I have been doing and it looks like I will keep it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1) Handle this case in delegate. You can get the URL that was loaded and triggered the webViewDidFinishLoad, if it is your URL with empty data - just ignore it.

2) Remove current instance of UIWebView and add a new one with nothing, like @Jeepston supposed. Just check this options for possible visual glitches on replacement. I am not sure what to do with empty WebView, but anyway. Good luck.

Comment: It was handled in delegate.  But I thought there might be a simpler solution.  Remove the current instance is not an option for me in this case.