# UIwebview + HTML with embedded video releasing only part of the memory

Tags: html, ios, memory, video, uiwebview

In my app I do have a UIwebview which is behaving quite well in regards of memory management.

When I open a video that is embedded into a website (this,specifically: http://bit.ly/1jT0OSE) - memory consumption goes up to 300 MB. I dont have any influence on the contents that is being shown.

When the webview (ARc) is closed again, only a part of it seems to be fully removed from memory.

If I stop close the webview before the video is fully played, Im able to recover a large part of the memory - but the longer it plays, the worse it gets.

I tried all the tricks and tips floating around SO, especially re caching but didnt get too far yet.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not don't sure but maybe you need just release your webview or load an empty html string?

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<html><head></head><body></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933315/clear-uiwebview-content-upon-dismissal-of-modal-view-iphone-os-3-0) theme

Answer (score 0):

There is no, as I know, clean solution, but you may try remove the `video` element from webView with Java script [JavaScript: remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3387427/1403732) before using all known hacks to release memory allocated by uiwebview.